# SQL query to display all columns with min, max and avg values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please could you help to get the query for the below table

```
  A  B   C   D
-----------------
  1  5   7  -5
  2  6   8  7
```

I need the Minimum, Maximum and Average values for all the columns listed vertically. The output should be as below. X, X, X are just sample letter instead of real min, max and avg values.

```
CN Min  Max   AVG 
----------------------
A  X    X     X
B  X    X     X
C  X    X     X 
D  X    X     X
```

CN = column name

Can anybody give me the query for this?

Comment: show your attempts or queries to solve this..

Comment: i am new to sql queries, just tried to use max,min,avg functions from sql but the output style what i was expected was different as above output from my question.

Comment: I'm just glad they're teaching MS SQL in school. Which school?

Comment: include your queries in your question so as that people can help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
;WITH CTE
(
SELECT 'A' as CN, tbl.a as nbr FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', tbl.b FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', tbl.c FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', tbl.d FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.CN,
    MAX(CTE.nbr) AS Max,
    MIN(CTE.nbr) AS Min,
    AVG(CTE.nbr) AS Avg
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.CN
```

Or with an [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT
    unpvt.CN,
    MAX(unpvt.nbr) AS Max,
    MIN(unpvt.nbr) AS Min,
    AVG(unpvt.nbr) AS Avg
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tbl.a,
        tbl.b,
        tbl.c,
        tbl.d
    FROM
        tbl
) AS p
UNPIVOT
(
    nbr FOR CN IN
    (a,b,c,d)
) AS unpvt
GROUP BY
    unpvt.CN
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CN, 
    MIN(Col) over (partition by CN) [Min],
    MAX(Col) over (partition by CN) [Max],
    AVG(Col) over (partition by CN) [Avg]
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM YourTable) p
UNPIVOT
   (Col FOR CN IN 
      (A, B, C, D)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Just to add, i have data something like this "-1E+30" which is not giving accurate values. how to avoid calculating values without these type of values?